# Where did the Google code playground go?

Tags: google-code, google-chart-api

I used to use the Google code playground to visualize and try Google APIs samples. I found it very useful.

But I can't find it anymore! Do you have any idea what happened to it and whether is has moved somewhere else?

---

The link was https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground

> The requested URL /apis/ajax/playground was not found on this server.
>   That’s all we know.

And it looked like:

[image]

Comment: That's what I mean, it doesn't link to the playground you can see on the picture. It was still there one week ago.

Comment: Yes, I will! More exactly: https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/forum?place=topic%2Fgoogle-apis-explorer-users%2FQaBFxd4c3EY%2Fdiscussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Developers Chart Gallery](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) include examples of charts and buttons with the text "CODE IT YOURSELF ON JSFIDDLE", so we could say that Google Code Playground, at least in relation to the Charts API, was moved to JSFIDDLE.